# APi incompatibility when using spring cloud contract

Tags: spring-cloud-contract

I'm trying to use spring cloud contract in a sample producer project. However I am seeing errors in my POM due to

```
Multiple annotations found at this line:
    - Execution default-generateTests of goal org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-contract-maven-plugin:1.2.4.RELEASE:generateTests failed: An API 
     incompatibility was encountered while executing org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-contract-maven-plugin:1.2.4.RELEASE:generateTests: 
     java.lang.VerifyError: Bad <init> method call from inside of a branch Exception Details: Location: org/springframework/cloud/contract/verifier/
     TestGenerator.<init>(Lorg/springframework/cloud/contract/verifier/config/ContractVerifierConfigProperties;)V @75: invokespecial Reason: Error exists in the 
     bytecode Bytecode: 0000000: b800 244d b800 2a9a 0006 a700 472a 2b2c 0000010: 122b 3212 02b9 0031 0200 1233 b800 39c0 0000020: 0033 2c12 
     3a32 123c 2c12 3d32 2bb9 0041 0000030: 0200 2c12 4232 1202 b900 3102 002b b900 0000040: 4605 0012 3cb8 0039 c000 3cb7 0049 a700 
     0000050: 2c2a 2bb8 004d 2c12 4e32 123c 2c12 4f32 0000060: 2bb9 0041 0200 b800 4d2b b900 4605 0012 0000070: 3cb8 0039 c000 3cb7 0049 b1 
     Stackmap Table: append_frame(@13,Object[#83])
```

I am using Spring Boot 1.5.14.RELEASE, Edgware.SR3, Java 1.8 and spring-cloud-contract-maven-plugin 1.2.4.RELEASE

I've tried playing around with versions of the plugin, Spring cloud and spring boot using examples from tutorials online for spring-cloud-contract yet I can't seem to get rid of the incompatibility error.

My code is here - https://github.com/craigmgordon/spring-cloud-contract/tree/Phase2/creditcheckservice-producer if it helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to successfully build your project. You have an bug in your contract (too many quotes)

```
import org.springframework.cloud.contract.spec.Contract;

Contract.make{
    request{
        method 'POST'
        url '/credit-scores'
        body """
            {
                "citizenNumber" : 1234
            }
            """ // you had an extra quote here
        headers{
            contentType applicationJson()
        }
    }
    response{
        status 200
        body """
            {
                "score" : "HIGH"
            }
            """
        headers{
            contentType applicationJson()
        }
    }
}
```

Execution

```
➜  creditcheckservice-producer git:(Phase2) ✗ ./mvnw clean install
...
Results :

Tests in error:
  CreditcardserviceTest.validate_shouldGrantACreditScoreOfHighToACitizen:24 » IllegalState

Tests run: 2, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 7.711 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2018-06-15T14:36:14+02:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.18.1:test (default-test) on project creditcheckservice-producer: There are test failures.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] Please refer to /Users/marcingrzejszczak2/repo/contract-issues/so/foo/spring-cloud-contract/creditcheckservice-producer/target/surefire-reports for the individual test results.
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
```

UPDATE:

It turned out that there was a mismatch in java versions

Comment: Thanks for the response Marcin but I'm still seeing the same issue. ( I had even commented out the entire groovy file but its the POM that is throwing the error). I've tried in the Spring Source Tool suite IDE and also just direct on the terminal but see the same issue. Could this be a java incompatibility? I'm using Java 1.8.0_11

Comment: That seems very old. That's what I use ➜  spring-cloud-static git:(master) ✗ java -version
java version "1.8.0_141"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_141-b15)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.141-b15, mixed mode)

Comment: Have now updated the java version to 1.8.0_171 and that seems to have resolved the issue. Thanks for your time Marcin. P.S. am enjoying your live lesson with Josh Long on Applied Continuous Delivery!